# Wireless stopped working sudenly

Tags: networking, wireless, internet, 17.04, broadcom

The wireless on my computer has sudenly stopped working, though wired i have connectivity. I couldn't find answers that would solve my issue, so I'm opening this question. I hope it's fixable.
Here are some info I thought it might help:

```
sudo lshw -c network
*-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Broadcom Limited
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: wlp3s0b1
   version: 01
   serial: 32:c2:79:cb:89:6e
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmsmac driverversion=4.10.0-42-generic firmware=610.812 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:17 memory:d4000000-d4003fff

lspci -v | grep -iA 7 network
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Limited BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
Subsystem: Askey Computer Corp. BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
Memory at d4000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
Kernel modules: bcma

iw dev
phy#0
Interface wlp3s0b1
    ifindex 3
    wdev 0x1
    addr 32:c2:79:cb:89:6e
    type managed
    txpower 30.00 dBm

memo@poc:~$ dmesg | grep bcma
[    1.334379] bcma: bus0: Found chip with id 0x4313, rev 0x01 and package 0x08
[    1.334414] bcma: bus0: Core 0 found: ChipCommon (manuf 0x4BF, id 0x800, rev 0x24, class 0x0)
[    1.334439] bcma: bus0: Core 1 found: IEEE 802.11 (manuf 0x4BF, id 0x812, rev 0x18, class 0x0)
[    1.334666] bcma: bus0: Core 2 found: PCIe (manuf 0x4BF, id 0x820, rev 0x11, class 0x0)
[    1.347583] bcma: bus0: Bus registered
[   21.079275] b43: probe of bcma0:1 failed with error -524
[   21.432623] brcmsmac bcma0:1: mfg 4bf core 812 rev 24 class 0 irq 17
[   23.298932] brcmsmac bcma0:1 wlp3s0b1: renamed from wlan0
[   26.736881] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: false (implement)
```

So basically the scan return empty (but it should because I can access it on my phone for example).

```
memo@poc:~$ sudo iw dev wlp3s0b1 scan
memo@poc:~$
```

Thank you all for your help, and please let me know if I should do something else